# A linear system of equations Ax = b has two diﬀerent solutions x = u and x = v.

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that the system has inﬁnitely many solutions?
I know suppose there are more unknowns  than equations. Then the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax = \theta \}$ is inﬁnite, so $Ax=b$ should have infinitely many solution, but how to say it in math language?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Check that $\lambda u + (1-\lambda ) v$ is a solution where $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Comment: `where λ∈(0,1)` Or even $\,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking,

$Rank(A)<n$
if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix